# Redirect, Handshake for apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have websites called `example.com` that allows me to make apps. It creates the `user name`, `encrypted token`, and `user token` for the user creating the app.

In order for the app to get activated it must get permission from the owner of the app. Similar to facebook. Have ever logged on to a website that says Log in with facebook. goes get permission from facebook and then facebook redirect back telling them its approve. I want to do something similar. So in `example.com`, when i press the activate button, it sends parameter et, usertoken, username to my mvc. Now i want to create a redirect back to `example.com` so i can complete a handshake necessary to activate the app, and refresh their main screen.

Comment: Do you have an adult website?

Comment: @Anon: the weirdest thing, I also just visited xxx.com, and I couldn't find where I can "make apps". :D

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for [OAuth](http://oauth.net/).

> OAuth provides a method for users to grant third-party access to their resources without sharing their passwords. It also provides a way to grant limited access (in scope, duration, etc.).

You can also look at: [dotnetopenauth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/)

> DotNetOpenAuth is a well established open source library that bring OpenID, OAuth, and ICard capabilities to the Microsoft .NET Framework.